# Cross Browser testing in TestNG with selected test cases

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Is it possible to run cross browser testing from TestNG with selected test cases on selected browser? For example. 1 - 5 test cases on IE and 6-10 on chrome etc.

Thanks,
Sudhakar

Comment: Have you read the TestNG documentation? What code and configs have you tried? Did you get an error or ?

Comment: Jeff, this was a question posted to me in a interview. I said yes, but when I thought through,I didn't get a logic to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible 
Let me show you how i have done this

1. Into TestNG suite file i will give browser name as parameter
2. Now add the code to fetch browser name in beforeTest method

   ```
   @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
   public void fetchSuiteConfiguration(ITestContext testContext) {
   targetBrowser=testContext.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("selenium.browser");}
   ```
3. Now initialize browser into beforeMethod

   ```
   @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
   public void setUp(Method method, ITestContext testContext)  {

   if (targetBrowser == null || targetBrowser.contains("firefox")) {
       /*initialize firefox driver here*/
   } else if (targetBrowser.contains("ie")) {
    /*initialize ie driver here*/
   } else if (targetBrowser.contains("opera")) {
    /*initialize opera driver here*/
   } else if (targetBrowser.contains("chrome")) {
    /*initialize Chrome driver here*/


   } 

   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.get(url);

   driver.manage().window().maximize();

   }
   ```

Comment: Patel, As per your code, Based on browser name as parameter the code will be initialize the browser and execute all the test cases. What I would like to do is at a single execution, TestNG should run on all the browsers but with different test cases(selected test cases).

Comment: @Veskar, then you need to specify the parameter inside the test tag like

<test  name="Test case : Verify search functionality with enter alphanumeric characters.">
  <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="chrome" />
  <classes>
   <class name="com.hawksearch.main.Tests">
    <methods>
     <include name="EnterAlphanumericCharacters" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>e

It will take parameter value only for particular Test.so it will open different browser for test you specified